# Why and how does ROUND_HALF_EVEN minimize cumulative error when applied repeatedly over a sequence of calculations?

Tags: java, rounding

I am told that ROUND_HALF_EVEN is the favored rounding mode for financial data calculations.  I am curious to know why and how this rounding mode would reduce the cumulative error as stated in javadoc BigDecimal 1.4.2.
Thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 12):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round-to-even_method):

> Despite the custom of rounding the
>   number 4.5 up to 5, in fact 4.5 is no
>   nearer to 5 than it is to 4 (it is 0.5
>   away from both). When dealing with
>   large sets of scientific or
>   statistical data, where trends are
>   important, traditional rounding on
>   average biases the data upwards
>   slightly. Over a large set of data, or
>   when many subsequent rounding
>   operations are performed as in digital
>   signal processing, the round-to-even
>   rule tends to reduce the total
>   rounding error, with (on average) an
>   equal portion of numbers rounding up
>   as rounding down. This generally
>   reduces upwards skewing of the result.

Answer (score 3):

Just to clarify, "round half even" rounds .5 up if the non-decimal part of the number is odd (5.5 -> 6), and rounds it down if the non-decimal part is even (4.5 -> 4) — i.e., to the nearest even number.

So 4.5 -> 4, 5.5 -> 6, 6.5 -> 6, etc.

For a truly random set of decimal numbers, this type of rounding will not skew the totals up or down significantly. So it is favoured as a "fair" rounding system in financial applications.

Comment: This example is incorrect. Should be:
4.5 -> 4, 5.5 -> 6, 6.5 -> 6 

From API docs: "Rounding mode to round towards the "nearest neighbor" unless both neighbors are equidistant, in which case, round towards the even neighbor."

Answer (score 2):

My impression is the same as the other two answers, namely that round-half-even when applied to a random number is equally likely to round up or down, so that over large sets of data there is no expected offset due to rounding.  But as far as I know, there's nothing special about round-half-even itself; round-half-odd (round n.5 to the nearest odd integer) would, I think, have the same property. Same with a random rounding policy, i.e. n.5 gets rounded up or down randomly with 50% probability.

Comment: round half odd introduces a slight bias away from zero.

Comment: Random produces 'unfair' totals on small samples.