# Why doesn't java.math.RoundingMode come with HALF_ODD rounding?

Tags: java, math

[java.math.RoundingMode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html) comes with HALF_EVEN mode which rounds number to nearest even neighbour in the case of equidistant, but why doesn't it come with HALF_ODD mode?

What is the simplest way of implementing HALF_ODD rounding in Java?

Comment: Why ? May be see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/792285/1163607).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this [link](http://www.pennedobjects.com/2010/06/adventures-in-net-rounding-part-2-exotic-rounding-algorithms/) can help you.

The solution proposed is:

```
public static int RoundToNearestRoundHalfToOdd(decimal value)
{
    // First round half toward positive infinity. Then if the fraction
    // part of the original value is 0.5 and the result of rounding is
    // even, then subtract one.
    var temp = (int)Math.Floor(value + 0.5m);
    if (value - Math.Floor(value) == 0.5m && temp % 2 == 0)
        temp -= 1;
    return temp;
}
```

It's in C# but I guess you can convert it for Java.

Also to help with your task, you can see the source code for the method [BigDecimal#divideAndRound](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/math/BigDecimal.java#BigDecimal.divideAndRound%28long,java.math.BigInteger,long,java.math.BigInteger,int,int,int%29) in the Java SDK where everything is happening.